# Combine all Google Material icon font requests into one

Tags: html, google-font-api, google-fonts

I was wondering if it possible to combine all requests below into one. Is it possible? If yes, how?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Icons+Round" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Icons+Two+Tone" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply stack the `family` URL parameters. Note that I've used the `css2` URL path variant.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Icons&family=Material+Icons+Outlined&family=Material+Icons+Round&family=Material+Icons+Sharp&family=Material+Icons+Two+Tone" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="material-icons-outlined">settings</span>
<span class="material-icons-round">check_circle</span>
<span class="material-icons-two-tone">account_circle</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be added this way using `|` to separate icon types:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
```